# Clean parsing of url query

Tags: python, urllib

Currently, whenever I need to parse a query string,  I was originally doing

```
 from urllib import parse

 path = parse.urlparse(self.path)
 query = parse.parse_qs(path.query)

 value = query[name][0]
```

But I didn't like the `[0]`s dotted around my code - it felt *wrong* in some hard to pinpoint way, so I realised I could do

```
 from urllib import parse

 path = parse.urlparse(self.path)
 query = dict(parse.parse_qsl(path.query))

 value = query[name]
```

That has the advantage of removing the `[0]`'s, but it risks discarding multiple values (which should be fine for my application, which shouldn't be receiving multiple values anyway).

Is there a cleaner way of parsing urlencoded strings, that gives you a `dict` of minimal values: the value if there's only one value, or a list if there's multiple?

A function to do so shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm curious if there's a library that does this so I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have such a dictionary `query`, you could always do

```
query = {[(k, v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v) for k, v in query.iteritems()]}
```

However, I really dislike this code, as it just produces stuff that is unintuitive later on.

Comment: `parse.parse_qs` returns a dict, [`parse.parse_qsl` returns a list of `(key,value)` pairs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qsl)